# Import a package without importing some of its modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, ipython

I have the following package called `biographs`:

```
biographs (folder)
 >biographs (package)
  >__init__.py
  >bspace.py
  >bpdb.py
  >bgraph.py
```

The `__init__.py` file imports the class `Pmolecule` from the module `pmolecule.py` only as follows:

```
from .pmolecule import Pmolecule
```

In turn, the `pmolecule.py` file imports the followin modules:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import bpdb
from . import bgraph
from . import bspace
```

Ipython has a completion feature that lets you see what are the available attributes of your object, e.g.,

```
In [1]: cd ~/biographs/
/Users/rdora/biographs

In [2]: import biographs

In [3]: biographs.
                   bgraph    Pmolecule
                   bpdb      pmolecule
                   bspace
```

As you can see after the `biographs.` the list of attributes is equivalent to the complete list of modules plus the class `Pmolecule` which is the only explicit import in `__init__.py`.

It seems logical because all those are necessary to use the class `Pmolecule`.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to `import` only the class without *having access* to the modules it uses.

Thanks

Comment: Just asking, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I work a lot in interactive mode with `ipython`, and often I find myself *surfing* through the modules' attributes to explore the package and see if there's a better functionality for what I do. The thing with this package that I wrote is that all the functions have only one goal, work as a kind of backend for the class `Pmolecule` and I would rather not see those modules available in the interactive mode because they are practically useless outside the context of said class and therefore, distracting?

Comment: If you are worried about performance issues, then partial imports don't matter. Whether you do, `from foo import bar` or `import foo`, the entire `foo` module will be compiled and imported. The only difference is what is made available in your namespace.

Comment: @COLDSPEED is indeed the namespace I am thinking about. For instance, I use the module `numpy` in this package in a module called `bspace` and I can access to it after importing the package `biographs` as `biographs.bspace.numpy`. I would like to know if there is a way to *hide* numpy. I know that you can hide certain objects from a namespace by starting its name with an underscore `_` I wonder if something similar has an effect for modules...

Comment: I would be interested in this as well. I'm testing deleting the imported modules or unnecessary functions (e.g. del np) but I'm not sure about the side effects. @rodgdor did you find an elegant solution?